# Shorten / detect URL javascript / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I do to detect an url in a textbox both http:// and just www. and then replace that with the string "URL" (it don't need to be clickable just need it to be that text) so when the checkbox toggles to true it should replace the url.

Example:

> some text www.mysite.com some more text

then when the checkbox is checked it should get "converted" to

> some text URL some more text

Here is are some code that i have now:
**[jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9rZr9/2/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="msg_txt_lenght">characters left: 38</div><form name="msg_form_name">
<input id="message_form" name="message" class="message_form_lim" type="text" maxlength="38" >
    </form>

<label><input id"short_url_id" name="short_url" type="checkbox" value="false" onclick="checkbox_url(this);">Shorten URL</label>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.message_form_lim').on('input', function (event) { 
    msg_lenght = (38 - this.value.length);
    document.getElementById("msg_txt_lenght").innerHTML = "characters left: " + msg_lenght;



});

function checkbox_url(cb)

    {
        if (cb.checked == true) {
            window.alert("true");
        }
        else{
            window.alert("false");
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance, hope my explanation makes sense.

Comment: Where's the code that tries to substitute?

Comment: You'll need a regular expression to match a string pattern like this, there are plenty on the net for matching URLs. I'm not sure I understand why you're replacing text like this, seems like it'd be easier to just reset the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenize the string & use regular expressions to identify each tokes is an URL.

Code:

```
        var new_string = '';
        var word_array = $("#message_form").val().split(" ");
         for (index = 0; index < word_array.length; ++index) 
         {
              if(word_array[index].match(regex))
              {
                   new_string+='URL ';
              }
              else
              {
                   new_string+=word_array[index]+' ';                                              
              }
              console.log(new_string);
         }
       $("#message_form").val(new_string);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rZr9/5/)

Comment: Thanks, I also want so when I toggle the checkbox to false it returns the text with the full url like it where before the toggle, I did this http://jsfiddle.net/9rZr9/8/ but I dont know why its not working just gets undefined, do you know whats wrong?